# Initializing a vector with istream_iterator before while loop, does this operation affect following loop?

Tags: c++, vector, istream-iterator

When adding `vector<string> vec(file_iter, eof);` before the while loop, that loop will run only once. Why?

```
istream_iterator<string> file_iter(in), eof;
map<string, size_t> word_cout;
vector<string> vec(file_iter, eof);
while (file_iter != eof)
{
 auto ret = word_cout.insert(make_pair(*file_iter, 1));
 if (ret.second == false) ++ret.first->second;
 ++file_iter;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construction here:

```
vector<string> vec(file_iter, eof);
```

passes a *copy* of the `file_iter` and `eof` iterators to the vector constructor, where it then abuses the former to load the vector with content. Whilst doing so the underlying stream `in` is continually read from until such time as a stream error or EOF is encountered. Once that happens, the stream is in error or eof state, the reads are done, and the vector is finished being populated.

Then, back to your next line of code:

```
while (file_iter != eof)
```

Remember, that's still the original `file_iter` before a copy of it was used to run the stream to eof. The initial prime of that iterator is still intact, but as soon as you advance it (`++file_iter`) the stream is discovered to be at eof, the iterator is set as such, and now the while-condition will compare as false.

If you want to load your vector *and* build the frequency map, use an iterator over the vector for the latter, or better still, a ranged-for loop:

```
istream_iterator<string> file_iter(in), eof;
map<string, size_t> word_cout;
vector<string> vec(file_iter, eof);
for (auto const& s : vec)
    ++word_count[s];
```

Now `vec` contains every word in your file, *and* your map contains the frequencies of said-same.

Comment: thanks for your reply!

but I am still feeling confused, and I want to know the reason why  ++file_iter leads to EOF?

Comment: I tried to explain that. The underlying stream on which the local `file_iter` is referencing is already there (EOF) because the vector-build using the istream iterators advanced that stream until it reached EOF. In theory you could just rewind the stream, but doing what I showed you is much easier, especially since you already have all the data anyway in that vector.